# Young adult novel about a warlock studying in a magical school

Tags: story-identification, novel, young-adult

It's the warlock's first time attending a magical school. In this school students are different magic users, but he is the only warlock. He has been repeatedly bullied throughout the school year; one time he is even injured. In the end he finishes the year and moves on to the next one.

He has studied spells and in the final demonstration casts a modified spell, which saves every one from dying due to the activation of a magical artefact (cylinder? orb?) by another student.

I would have read this story near 2015.

Comment: Can you clarify what makes a Warlock different from other magicians on this book? It's a term with a lot of different uses.

Comment: There are several types of magic users in book: warlock, sorcerer and some more (I don't remember). Warlock is considered weakest but he studies (as I remember) every aspect of different sorcerer magic used by his classmates.

Comment: This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The book is called *[Caster's Spell](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/36403302-caster-s-spell)* (A Mage Tale Book 1) by E. D. Watley.

> The first Warlock to enter a formal school of magic, Wesley, delves into a world he scarcely knows, ill-equipped, unprepared, and by far unwelcome. Adamant in proving that his kind belongs, he aspires to someday reach the title of All Powerful Mage—a task, he learns, much easier said than done.
>
> With hundreds of students itching to take him down, instructors baring a fanatical intent to fail him, and an unfolding mystery behind the relic created by a shroud of a man, known as Benjamin Caster, does Wesley stand a chance at passing the final exams? He certainly hopes so...
>
> ...and the rest of the world depends on it.

Comment: Really good of you to self-answer, that's appreciated! :) But for the sake of future readers searching for the same book, could you please [edit] into your answer the elements that match what you described in the question? As well as a summary, for instance?

Comment: @aLLex: I hope you don't mind, but I added a Goodreads link and its summary to your answer.